# Check if point is within cone

Tags: python, 3d, geometry

So basically I'm defining a cone in a 3D space. The cone is defined by a base center, base radius, and top radius.

I want to make a function that can take those parameters and determine if a given point is inside the cone.

Here is what I have:

```
import math

class Vector:
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.X = pos[0]
        self.Y = pos[1]
        self.Z = pos[2]

class ConeShape:
    def __init__(self, pos, height, bRadius, tRadius):
        self.X = pos[0]
        self.Y = pos[1]
        self.Z = pos[2]

        self.baseRadius = bRadius
        self.topRadius = tRadius

        self.Height = height

    def Position(self):
        pos = [self.X, self.Y, self.Z]
        return Vector(pos)

    def ContainsPoint(self, x, y, z):
        z -= self.Z

        permRadius = (self.baseRadius - self.topRadius) * (z / self.Height)
        print(("Test: {0:0.2f}").format(permRadius))

        pointRadius = (math.sqrt((x - self.X) ** 2 + (y - self.Y) ** 2))

        if (z <= self.Height and z >= 0.0) and (pointRadius <= permRadius):
            return True
        return False

def main():
    cone = ConeShape([0.0, 0.1, 0.0], 10.0, 5.0, 0.1)
    if (cone.ContainsPoint(0.0, 0.1, 0.0)):
        print("Yes!")

    cone = ConeShape([0.0, 0.1, 0.0], 10.0, 5.0, 0.0)
    if (cone.ContainsPoint(0.0, 0.1, 0.0)):
        print("Yes!")

main()
```

My `permRadius` (permittable radius) is wrong, for sure. I'm not sure what else is wrong. So how do I determine the permittable radius given the height?

Comment: The top radius means you are having a truncated cone? Then the values you have are not sufficient to define a cone in 3D space. The dimesions of the cone and the center of the base are clear, but the rotation is not.

Comment: @KlausD. No, it's not rotated. It's not going to be rotated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `permRadius` formula is wrong. Right one (check for `z = 0, z=Height, z=Height/2`):

```
 permRadius = self.baseRadius - (self.baseRadius - self.topRadius) * (z /self.Height)
```

Comment: This is the answer to my question, but my code is still failing. I'm not saying it's your fault.

Comment: What test is failing?

Comment: The same code as posted, but with your fix. Going by logic the second test with "(0.0, 0.1, 10.0)" as the test point should fail.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I was thinking I had the cone center set at [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]. Thanks!